# Get posts by group in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I have Users who belong to Groups and can create Posts.

On each Group page, I'm trying to display all Posts by Users in that particular Group (newest to oldest). This is the code I've tried so far, but it's showing all Posts by every User, regardless of what Group the User belongs to.

Here's the `groups_controller.rb`:

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    if logged_in?
      @feed_items = Post.latest_posts_by_group(@group)
    end
  end
end
```

And in `post.rb`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.latest_posts_by_group(group_id)
    Post.find_by_sql(['select posts.*
      from groups
      inner join users
      on users.group_id = groups.id
      inner join posts
      on posts.user_id = user_id
      where groups.id = ?
      order by created_at desc', group_id])
  end
end
```

`user.rb` (well, at least the associations):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :posts
end
```

`group.rb` (again, just showing the associations):

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

Comment: Can you share the relationship between the models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use rails built in association helpers rather than constructing a SQL query manually. In this case

```
class  Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :group, through: :user

class  User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :posts

class  Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :posts, through: :users
```

When you construct these associations correctly, rails generates methods like `@group.posts` for you automatically.

You should note, however that the foreign keys have to be named a certain way for the associations to work, but from your SQL query I see that you have already done that by naming the foreign keys `group_id` and `user_id` in your `Users` and `Posts` tables, respectively.

For further reference: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: When I tried this, it gave me the following error: "Could not find the association :user in model Group"...any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added `has_many :users` to Group. I'll edit it now. And changing `belongs_to :group, through: :user` in Post to a `has_one`, thanks for catching that @Hiasinho

Comment: Wonderful, this works! Is is faster/more efficient than the scope method advocated by Hiasinho?

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in the efficiency of your program, but I find this way a little bit more readable. They should both work.

Comment: This method (through association) is better, because it is simpler. Just wanted to add an alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a scope. Join the `:user` association and put a condition on `users.group.id`. The following code should do it.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :user
  has_one :group, through: :user

  scope :latest_posts_by_group, ->(group) {
    joins(:user).
    where(users: {group_id: group.id}).
    reorder(created_at: :desc)
  }
end
```

This creates a SQL like this:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts
  INNER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id
WHERE users.group_id = ?
ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC
```

If you want, you can also take the `groups` table into account. But it is not necessary, as you have the `group_id` in the `users` table.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :user
  has_one :group, through: :user

  scope :latest_posts_by_group, ->(group) {
    joins(:group).
    where(groups: {id: group.id}).
    reorder(created_at: :desc)
  }
end
```

This creates a SQL like this:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts
  INNER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id
  INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = users.group_id
WHERE groups.id = ?
ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC
```

Have a look at the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) for further details.

Comment: Thanks @Hiasinho! With a slight alteration to your first suggestion, it works. I used `scope :latest_posts_by_group, ->(group) {joins(:user).where(users: {group_id: group.id}).reorder('created_at desc')}`. I wish I could accept more than once answer, since both worked and were quite helpful.